# How to pin FEATURE ATTRIBUTE FORM window in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, identify

When I identify a feature in QGIS the window of IDENTIFY FEAtURE is open and the FEatURE ATTRIBUTE FORM window too.

The form of the attribute table is open in the middle of the QGIS window and I want it to be open somewhere in the corner.

Every time I click to identify new feature - the attribute form is opening in a new window. How can I prevent this?

Comment: Have you tried dragging it to the side? What happens, if you drag it and close it? Does it open in the middle again or not?

Comment: I have tried, but nothing. It just move  where you drag and in the next click(identify) it will show again in the middle

Comment: Have you dragged and snapped it to the side?

Comment: Yes, I tried. Nothing happens :(

Comment: Have you made any modifications to your QGIS?

Answer (score 4):

> Every time I click to identify new feature - the attribute form is opening in a new window. How can I prevent this?

You can prevent open the *Features Form* every time you identify a feature, disabling the *Auto open form* option in the *Identify Results* panel:

[image: 1]

*Identify Results* is a panel (not a form) and can be docked by drag and drop. Also, panels (like *Identify Results*, *Layer Styling* and *Processing Toolbox*) can be docked together as tabs, so *Identify Results* can be opened always as a panel tab.

I don't know how to dock *Features Form*.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I don't want to deactivate "Auto Open form" because I need it (BCS I have put some attachment and I want to click on their link to access them). It would be much better to dock or pin the form of identifying results. :/

Comment: "the form of identifying results" is an ambiguity. The Feature Form is the form that is opened each time a feature is created. Identify Results is the panel wich is opened each time a feature is consulted by the identify tool. Identify Results Panel can be docked by drag and drop, and contains all the attributes of the feature. You can click on them if contain a URL type data.

Comment: Yes - you are right. I'm going to edit it. Thank you